# How to enable Version Control window in android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

For certain of my branches, I cannot get a version control window. So for example, if I go into branch `develop`, then the window shows; if I go into `master` it’s gone and there is nothing I can do to bring it back. I try to trick it by going from develop to master. But as soon as I get to master, it is gone again. The problem is relatively new (7 days). It didn’t use to be like that. Any ideas how I might fix it?

I usually use the window for easy access to my log of commits

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I got it finally! I needed to click on `menu > VCS > Enable Version Control Integration > Git`

Comment: My version of Android Studio (v2.1.2 on Ubuntu) doesn't have that option

Comment: And my Android Studio version is 2.3.3 and it doesn't have that option, too!

Comment: Also check whether git path is properly set. Go to Preferences -> Version Control -> Git -> Path to git executable

Answer (score 8):

For latest versions of Android studio, you can find this option in View -> Tools Windows -> Version Control

Answer (score 1):

View -> Tools Windows -> Commit

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it under `Settings > Version Control > Commit`.
My version is: `Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the previous answers did not work on `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1`.

The solution was to open the Git Commit window, click the gear icon, click `Switch to commit dialog`. Press the hotkey or `Git > Commit` to open the window.