# Android Stuidio 2.1.2 enable version control integration

Tags: git, ubuntu, android-studio, version-control, ide

Most sources I go to, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188720/how-to-enable-version-control-window-in-android-studio) and [many of the top google search results](http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/), say that there should be an option under the VCS menu that says "Enable Version Control Integration", but I don't have one.

This is what my menu looks like:

[image: Dropdown menu]
(submenus can be provided if needed)

I'm currently running Android Studio version 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I remember accidentally enabling version control before, but I've been unable to do so since then.

I know that it isn't already enabled because the option for git add is grayed out whenever I try to add a file and filenames are not colored based on whether or not they are added.

Comment: Are you trying that menu with a loaded project *already* in a local git repo?

Comment: @VonC I've tried with and without, but the integration didn't work either way.

Comment: If you don't see an hidden .git folder, that means you didn't try with a local git repo though.

Comment: @VonC Sorry for the vagueness; I've tried in two separate projects, one with and one without. I'm about to try the suggested option in the one with the local it repo.

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting vcs.xml file from .idea folder of your project

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to see that option because your project already has git integration. If you still want to see this option then delete the hidden `.git` folder inside your project directory.

Comment: If git is enabled already then why is the menu option for git add grayed out?

Comment: While there is a hidden `.gitignore`, there's no hidden `.git` folder

Comment: can you upload a picture of your project folder?